# check options in multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to find a way to check my options in different select boxes (total: 4). 
The boxes include the same data in value/text.

How do I avoid that the option select is the same? (I use it for an sorting feature).
And how can i integrate it in the current jquery script. (I use ajax-post to parse data).

***This is how it should not be:*** 
[image]

**Select one:**

```
<ul>
<li class="move-img">
<select style="width:150px;"id="modul1" onchange="$.modules.options(this,1);">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">name</option>
<option value="2">name2</option>
</select>
</li>
```

**Select two**

```
<ul>
<li class="move-img">
<select style="width:150px;"id="modul2" onchange="$.modules.options(this,2);">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">name</option>
<option value="2">name2</option>
</select>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.modules = {

/*  Get price for option-modules */
options: function(module_id,show_divid){

    var modul = $(module_id).val();

    if(modul != 0){     
        //show price 
        $("#showprice"+show_divid).html('<div class="ajax_loader left"></div>').fadeTo(300,0.25,function(){

            var $show_price = $(this); // div tag

            $.post('/ajax/modules/get_prices/',{check_data:'send_data',get_module_prices_id:modul},function(data){
                $show_price.fadeTo(200,100,function(){

                    $show_price.html(data.module_price);
                });
            },'json');
        });
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should not edit the problematic parts of your question, as it may confuse the later comers and it would not make sense any more. Afterall, it is the answerer's job to point out the problems you stated. So, after @ShankarSangoli's answer, does that mean your question is no longer a question?

Comment: Okay.. Sorry. It's still a question, he came with some feedback how to use the function better. Not a solution to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder whether this is what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/william/K7nTr/.

It checks whether the value has already been selected. If it has, revert to the first value and alert the user.

```
$.modules = {

    /*  Get price for option-modules */
    options: function(module_id, show_divid) {

        var modul = $(module_id).val();

        if (modul != 0) {
            var selector = ".move-img option:selected[value=" + modul + "]";
            if ($(selector).length > 1) { // see if this value has been selected elsewhere
                alert('The value has been selected. Try again');
                $('option:eq(0)', module_id).attr('selected', 'selected');
                return;
            }

            //show price
            $("#showprice" + show_divid).html('<div class="ajax_loader left"></div>').fadeTo(300, 0.25, function() {

                var $show_price = $(this); // div tag
                $.post('/ajax/modules/get_prices/', {
                    check_data: 'send_data',
                    get_module_prices_id: modul
                }, function(data) {
                    $show_price.fadeTo(200, 100, function() {

                        $show_price.html(data.module_price);
                    });
                }, 'json');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for! it works! Now I can return to my project and play more with that feature. Thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

In `onchange="$.modules.options('modul1',1);"` you dont have to pass `modul1`, you can just pass `this` which will point to the changing select box. This applies to both the select boxes. You have few js error in your code, try this.

```
$.modules = {

/*  Get price for option-modules */
options: function(module_id,show_divid){

    var modul = $(module_id).val();

    if(modul != 0){
        //show price 
        $("#showprice"+show_divid).html('<div class="ajax_loader left"></div>').fadeTo(300,0.25,function(){

            var $show_price = $(this); // div tag

            $.post('/ajax/modules/get_prices/',{check_data:'send_data',get_module_prices_id:modul},function(data){
                $show_price.fadeTo(200,100,function(){

                    $show_price.html(data.module_price);
                });
            },'json');
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. in html, replace the onChange

```
onchange="$.modules.options(this);"
```

in jquery, replace:

```
    options: function(module){

var modul = $("option:selected", module).val();
```

and replace too

```
if(modul.length == 0);
    else{
```

by

```
if( modul.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //or document.forms[0].elements;  
   var cbs = []; //will contain all checkboxes  
   var checked = []; //will contain all checked checkboxes  
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {  
   cbs.push(inputs[i]);  
   if (inputs[i].checked) {  
     checked.push(inputs[i]);  
   }  
 }  
}  
var nbCbs = cbs.length; //number of checkboxes  
var nbChecked = checked.length; //number of checked checkboxes  

for(var i=0;i<checked.length;i++)
{
if(checked[i].value=checked[i+1].value)
{
alert('Not allowed');
}
}
```

Comment: Dosen't seems to change anything. Its select options not inputs. (could that be why nothing happen?)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got you right here.
But my following example allows each option to be selected only once.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var ValidateOptions = function (module) {
        var selectedValue = $('option:selected', module).attr('value');
        var collectionWithoutCurrent = $('.move-img select').not(module);

        $('option').show();

        collectionWithoutCurrent.each(function () {
            $(this).children('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').toggle();
        });
    };
</script>
<ul>
    <li class="move-img">
        <select style="width: 150px;" id="modul1" onchange="ValidateOptions($(this))">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">name</option>
            <option value="2">name2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="move-img">
        <select style="width: 150px;" id="modul2" onchange="ValidateOptions($(this))">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">name</option>
            <option value="2">name2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What should your code exactly do? (in output). When I try it and check console.log - nothing happen. :-/ What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: This is only for the selection of the dropdowns. You'll need to collect the data afterwards or just hang up into the change event.